# sabredav carddav not working on ios, barily working on android

Tags: php, ios, caldav, carddav, sabredav

I'm integrating sabredav into my webapplication, the connection between my app -> sabredab seems to be fine. Using the browser I can get to all the vcards needed.

On Android when I use the url

```
example.org/sabredavcontroller/index/addressbooks/principalID/addressbookID
```

it sync perfectly

However on ios (6) it goes at example.org/.well-known/carddav

Which i've redirected to example.org/sabredavcontroller/index/ but then it does nothing with it and tries other urls which don't work either and errors out.

This is the accesslog from when ios tries to set up an account to carddav:

```
projectnexys.com:80 192.168.125.24 - - [22/Mar/2013:10:41:58 +0100] "PROPFIND /.well-known/carddav HTTP/1.1" 302 574 "-" "iOS/6.1.2 (10B146) Preferences/1.0"
projectnexys.com:80 192.168.125.24 - - [22/Mar/2013:10:41:59 +0100] "PROPFIND /sabredavcontroller/index/ HTTP/1.1" 401 985 "-" "iOS/6.1.2  (10B146) Preferences/1.0"
projectnexys.com:80 192.168.125.24 - member2@bla.bla [22/Mar/2013:10:41:59 +0100] "PROPFIND /sabredavcontroller/index/ HTTP/1.1" 207 1423 "-" "iOS/6.1.2 (10B146) Preferences/1.0"
projectnexys.com:80 192.168.125.24 - - [22/Mar/2013:10:42:00 +0100] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 302 818 "-" "iOS/6.1.2 (10B146) Preferences/1.0"
projectnexys.com:80 192.168.125.24 - - [22/Mar/2013:10:42:01 +0100] "PROPFIND /account HTTP/1.1" 200 2107 "-" "iOS/6.1.2 (10B146) Preferences/1.0"
projectnexys.com:80 192.168.125.24 - - [22/Mar/2013:10:42:01 +0100] "PROPFIND /principals/ HTTP/1.1" 404 890 "-" "iOS/6.1.2 (10B146) Preferences/1.0"
```

(To clarify: the first line is to find out the root of sabredav via redirect: 301
             the secondline is a request to the root but it needs an username/pw
             the third is the same as second but with authentication
             and then it gives up on this url and tries other options
)

The result from the third line is, using curl with this command:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml" -u "member2@bla.bla:bla" --request PROPFIND  projectnexys.com/sabredavcontroller/index/ | xmllint --format -
```

-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns" xmlns:card="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav">
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/sabredavcontroller/index/</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:getlastmodified>Fri, 22 Mar 2013 09:36:52 GMT</d:getlastmodified>
        <d:resourcetype>
          <d:collection/>
        </d:resourcetype>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/sabredavcontroller/index/principals/</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:getlastmodified>Fri, 22 Mar 2013 09:36:52 GMT</d:getlastmodified>
        <d:resourcetype>
          <d:collection/>
        </d:resourcetype>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/sabredavcontroller/index/addressbooks/</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:getlastmodified>Fri, 22 Mar 2013 09:36:52 GMT</d:getlastmodified>
        <d:resourcetype>
          <d:collection/>
        </d:resourcetype>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

Could anyone give me tips on what might be going wrong?

Ps. I am using SabreDAV http://sabre.io/ I can't create a new tag yet tho 'cause of reputation

Comment: A common mistake is not loading the ACL plugin, which is required. Also, what do you have for a base url?

Comment: You were exactly right, it took some fiddling to get the groups right, but not it works like a charm, if you'd add it as an answer I'd accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ACL plugin. CardDAV requires it!